# Cauchy's integral with sin used in it

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

$$
\int_{0}^{2 \pi} \frac{1}{5-3 \sin \theta} d \theta
$$

hello, i think there are multiple ways to solve this question, but i need to use Cauchy's. would you help me with it? thanks

Comment: What have you tried? You'll have to show what you've done to get the answer here. Take a tour: [math.stackexchange.com/tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour). You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context by stating what you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance: [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $z=e^{i\theta}$ and then $\sin\theta=\frac1{2i}(z-\frac1z), d\theta=\frac1{iz}dz$. So
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_{0}^{2 \pi} \frac{1}{5-3 \sin \theta} d \theta&=&\int_{|z|=1}\frac{1}{5-3\cdot\frac1{2i}(z-\frac1z)}\frac1{iz}dz\\
&=&\int_{|z|=1}\frac{2}{3z^2-10iz-3}dz\\
&=&\int_{|z|=1}\frac{2}{3(z-z_1)(z-z_2)}dz.
\end{eqnarray}
Note that $z_{1}=3i,z_2=\frac{i}{3}$ are roots of $3z^2-10iz-3=0$ but only $z_2$ is inside $|z|=1$ and hence
$$ \int_{0}^{2 \pi} \frac{1}{5-3 \sin \theta} d \theta=2\pi i\frac{2}{3(z_2-z_1)}=\frac{\pi}{2}.$$